# Why I cannot git stage files when using git inside Transmit Disk feature?

Tags: git, sftp

I've mounted my server as disc, using https://panic.com/transmit/#disks

I've created a new git repository inside it, but when I try to stage files it gives me and error:

error: file write error (Input/output error)
fatal: unable to write sha1 file

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I get the same error with Forklift 2. I think when you stage files, you're really editing repo/.git/index, and I verified that I can edit that file from the command line... so I'm not sure why git is complaining.

Comment: I installed [sshfs](http://osxfuse.github.io/) to mount an sftp server as a volume, and it works with git (albeit without the pretty interface).